# difference between the grow() methods in java.util.Stack and java.util.ArrayDeque

Tags: java, stack, arraydeque

I came across the grow() method for when a stack is full, but when I saw there was a difference in the grow() function in the arraydeque, I wondered what the difference actually was.

Does anyone know the answer to this?

```
if (s == elementData.length){
    elementData = this.grow()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "you saw there was a difference in the grow() function in other data containers"?

Comment: It would help if you showed the differences in the question.

Comment: It looks to me as if the strategy used for `grow()` is basically the same for `Stack` (and `Vector`) and for `ArrayDeque`.  The `Vector` class also has a constructor option for growing by a fixed increment (rather than doubling), but `Stack` doesn't use it.

Comment: FYI, the `Stack` class is legacy. As noted in its Javadoc: *A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.* I suggest you ignore `Stack` altogether.

Comment: @LouisWasserman sorry, with other data containers, I meant ArrayDeque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually I found out that the differences are the following:

Stack growable:

1. Tight Strategy : Add a constant amount to the old stack (N+c)
2. Growth Strategy : Double the size of old stack (2N)

Arraydeque growable:

'Array deques have no capacity restrictions and they grow as necessary to support usage.' [arraydeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)